# WPF/ChromiumWebBrowser executing Javascript function (With parameters!)

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, chromium-embedded

So I'm working on a WPF app that has a web page self hosting, and in my Javascript I need to use some data from my C#.  I'm wondering if there's any way (in WPF/C#) to invoke a Javascript function WITH a parameter, or if the best way to accomplish this would just be to dump the parameters to a text file and use the Javascript to read it in again, which I'd strongly prefer not to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for responding, but the class I'm using is actually the ChromiumWebBrowser, part of CefSharp.  I didn't think to google that and i actually found this [How to pass inputs to javascript functions with cefsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269534/how-to-pass-inputs-to-javascript-functions-with-cefsharp)

Thanks!